# TLocationSensor не работает на delphi fmx 10.3.1 RIO, не работает на delphi fmx 10.1.2 push сообщения

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

`TLocationSensor` не работает на delphi fmx 10.3.1 RIO, не работает на delphi fmx 10.1.2 push сообщения

Использование типа такого кода:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  Androidapi.JNI.Location, Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os,Androidapi.Helpers, FMX.Layouts, FMX.ListBox, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation;

type

  TLocationListener = class;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    CheckBox2: TCheckBox;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Label6: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    { Private declarations }

  private
    FLocationManager : JLocationManager;
    locationListener : TLocationListener;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
    { Public declarations }
    procedure onLocationChanged(location: JLocation);
  end;

  TLocationListener = class(TJavaLocal, JLocationListener)
  private
    [weak]
    FParent : TForm1;
  public
    constructor Create(AParent : TForm1);
    procedure onLocationChanged(location: JLocation); cdecl;
    procedure onProviderDisabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onProviderEnabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onStatusChanged(provider: JString; status: Integer; extras: JBundle); cdecl;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses FMX.Helpers.Android, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;

{ TLocationListener }

constructor TLocationListener.Create(AParent: TForm1);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FParent := AParent;
end;

procedure TLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location: JLocation);
begin
  FParent.onLocationChanged(location);
end;

procedure TLocationListener.onProviderDisabled(provider: JString);
begin

end;

procedure TLocationListener.onProviderEnabled(provider: JString);
begin

end;

procedure TLocationListener.onStatusChanged(provider: JString; status: Integer;
  extras: JBundle);
begin

end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LocationManagerService: JObject;
  iter : JIterator;
  location : JLocation;
begin
  if not Assigned(FLocationManager) then
  begin
    LocationManagerService := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap((LocationManagerService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    if not Assigned(locationListener) then
      locationListener := TLocationListener.Create(self);
    FLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 10, locationListener,
        TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper);
  end;
  iter := FLocationManager.GetAllProviders.Iterator;
  ListBox1.Clear;
  while iter.hasNext do
  begin
    ListBox1.Items.Add(JStringToString(iter.next.ToString));
  end;
  CheckBox1.IsChecked := FLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER);
  CheckBox2.IsChecked := FLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
  location := FLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER);
  onLocationChanged(location);
end;

destructor TForm1.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(locationListener) then
    FLocationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.onLocationChanged(location: JLocation);
begin
  Label4.Text := location.getLatitude.ToString;
  Label5.Text := location.getLongitude.ToString;
  Label6.Text := location.getAltitude.ToString;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено, но довольно неоднозначное употребление tLocationSensor работает под Delphi FMX 10.3.1 RIO

unit Form_Principal;

```
interface

uses   System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes,
System.Classes, System.Variants,   FMX.Types, FMX.Controls,
FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Layouts,   FMX.WebBrowser,
FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Objects,  
System.Permissions, System.Sensors, System.Sensors.Components;

type   TForm1 = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser: TWebBrowser;
    Layout1: TLayout;
    Switch: TSwitch;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Layout2: TLayout;
    RoundRect1: TRoundRect;
    lbl_endereco: TLabel;
    LocationSensor: TLocationSensor;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SwitchClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure LocationSensorLocationChanged(Sender: TObject; const OldLocation,
      NewLocation: TLocationCoord2D);
    procedure lbl_enderecoClick(Sender: TObject);   private
    { Private declarations }
    Location: TLocationCoord2D;
    FGeocoder: TGeocoder;

    {$IFDEF ANDROID}
     Access_Fine_Location, Access_Coarse_Location : string;
     procedure DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject;
              const APermissions: TArray<string>; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
     procedure LocationPermissionRequestResult
                (Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TArray<string>;
                const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
    {$ENDIF}

    procedure OnGeocodeReverseEvent(const Address: TCivicAddress);

  public
    { Public declarations }   end;

var   Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses FMX.DialogService

{$IFDEF ANDROID} ,Androidapi.Helpers, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
Androidapi.JNI.Os {$ENDIF}

;

{$IFDEF ANDROID}

procedure TForm1.DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject;   const
APermissions: TArray<string>; const APostRationaleProc: TProc); var 
I: Integer;   RationaleMsg: string; begin   for I := 0 to
High(APermissions) do   begin
    if (APermissions[I] = Access_Coarse_Location) or (APermissions[I] = Access_Fine_Location) then
      RationaleMsg := 'Приложению требуется доступ к GPS, чтобы узнать ваше местоположение'   end;

  TDialogService.ShowMessage(RationaleMsg,
    procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      APostRationaleProc;
    end) end;

procedure TForm1.LocationPermissionRequestResult   (Sender: TObject;
const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults:
TArray<TPermissionStatus>); var
         x : integer; begin   if (Length(AGrantResults) = 2) and
    (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) and
    (AGrantResults[1] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
    Form1.LocationSensor.Active := true   else   begin
    Switch.IsChecked := false;
    TDialogService.ShowMessage
      ('Невозможно получить доступ к GPS, потому что приложение не имеет доступа')   end;

end;

{$ENDIF}

procedure TForm1.OnGeocodeReverseEvent(const Address:
TCivicAddress); var
        msg : string; begin
        msg :=  Address.AdminArea + ', ' +
                Address.CountryCode + ', ' +
                Address.CountryName + ', ' +
                Address.FeatureName + ', ' +
                Address.Locality + ', ' +
                Address.PostalCode + ', ' +
                Address.SubAdminArea + ', ' +
                Address.SubLocality + ', ' +
                Address.SubThoroughfare + ', ' +
                Address.Thoroughfare;

        TDialogService.ShowMessage(msg); end;

procedure TForm1.LocationSensorLocationChanged(Sender: TObject;  
const OldLocation, NewLocation: TLocationCoord2D); var
        lt, lg, url : string; begin
        Location := NewLocation;
        lt := StringReplace(Format('%2.6f', [NewLocation.Latitude]), ',', '.', [rfReplaceAll]);
        lg := StringReplace(Format('%2.6f', [NewLocation.Longitude]), ',', '.', [rfReplaceAll]);

        LocationSensor.Active := false;
        Switch.IsChecked := false;

        url := 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=' + lt + ',' + lg;
        WebBrowser.Navigate(url); end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); begin
        {$IFDEF ANDROID}
        Access_Coarse_Location := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        Access_Fine_Location := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        {$ENDIF} end;



procedure TForm1.lbl_enderecoClick(Sender: TObject); begin
        try
                // Tratando a instancia TGeocoder...
                if not Assigned(FGeocoder) then
                begin
                        if Assigned(TGeocoder.Current) then
                                FGeocoder := TGeocoder.Current.Create;

                        if Assigned(FGeocoder) then
                                FGeocoder.OnGeocodeReverse := OnGeocodeReverseEvent;
                end;

                // Tratar a traducao do endereco...
                if Assigned(FGeocoder) and not FGeocoder.Geocoding then
                        FGeocoder.GeocodeReverse(Location);
        except
                showmessage('Erro Geocoder');
        end; end;

procedure TForm1.SwitchClick(Sender: TObject); begin
        if Switch.IsChecked then
        begin
                {$IFDEF ANDROID}
                PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([Access_Coarse_Location,
                                                       Access_Fine_Location],
                                                       LocationPermissionRequestResult,
                                                       DisplayRationale);
                {$ENDIF}

                {$IFDEF IOS}
                LocationSensor.Active := true;
                {$ENDIF}
        end; end;
```

Comment: Отформатируйте нормально код, пожалуйста